# Comparing strings in EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

How to compare the strings in JSP EL. I tried to do

```
<select name="groupa" style="width: 170px">
   <option value ="-1">no group</option>
 <c:forEach var="gr" items="${sessionScope['entrantsAcceptor'].groups}">
  <option value="${gr.idGroup}" <c:if test="${gr.code == param.group}">checked</c:if> >${gr.code}</option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

But it doesn't work(there are no any `checked` in options of select(though I pass correct argument)). Also I have tried to do

```
${gr.code eq param.group}
```

but it also has no effect

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to compare two strings in a jsp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900843/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-a-jsp)

Comment: please try to search before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EL looks fine and should work fine. Rightclick the page in webbrowser and choose *View Source*. Do you see the `checked` attribute being set in the right place in the generated HTML?

But this is after all not the right attribute. On a HTML `<option>` element you need to set the `selected` attribute, not the `checked` attribute.

```xml
<c:if test="${gr.code == param.group}">selected</c:if>
```