# How to write a <option> selected attribute in haml in a jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, haml

I would like to output this jsp in haml:

```
<select>
  <option ${page.defaultCar=="Volvo" ? "selected" : ""}>Volvo</option>
  <option ${page.defaultCar=="Saab" ? "selected" : ""}>Saab</option>
</select>
```

The solution how found at the moment is to escape the entire line line so:

```
\<option ${page.defaultCar=="Volvo" ? "selected" : ""}>Volvo</option>
```

Just wondering if there is a smarter way to do it.

Thank you ;)

Comment: You should use `.equals()` method to compare values.`==` is used when you want to compare references.

Comment: @Hardik: you're confusing Java with EL.

Comment: @BalusC: My Bad.. I just read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900843/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-a-jsp. Will take care in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<option '${page.defaultCar=="Volvo" ? "selected" : ""}'>Volvo</option>
```

Comment: that will output: <option '${page.defaultCar=="Volvo" ? "selected" : ""}' > Volvo </option>. I'll if it works in a few hours.