# How to compare two variables in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am using the following code to compare two variables, but it seems it has an error as the page does not get loaded at all.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900843/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-a-jsp) my code should be correct but surprisingly does not work.

If I remove the  `<c:when>` line it shows 
                                     the values of `${name}` and `${myvar.employee.name}`.

```
<c:forEach var="myvar" items="${user.names}">

    ${name}
    ${myvar.employee.name}

    <c:when test="${name eq myvar.employee.name}">
        hello
    </c:when>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure with `<c:when>` requires  `<c:choose>`

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${your condition here}">
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

otherwise you will get error.

Answer (score 3):

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17959353/185722) has pointed out, you cannot have non-wrapped `<c:when>` in your code.

But it looks like, in your case, `<c:choose>` is not required, because you have only a single clause.  In this case `<c:if>` may be a better option:

```
<c:if test="${name eq myvar.employee.name}">
  hello
</c:if>
```