# JSP conditional statement

Tags: java, jsp

I have some code that I am using to grab the page name, and I want to compare the variable to a string - but the statement always returns "true".

```
<%
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
%>

<c:if test="${pageName != 'home.html'}" >
<script src="<%= designPath %>/javascripts/constants.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= designPath %>/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= designPath %>/javascripts/cart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</c:if>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900843/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-a-jsp

Comment: @Doorknob 5782523*rd* haha ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already using pure Java code to get the uri and page name, you might as well use pure java code for the if-statement too. Since you're already breaking the sacrosanct "no Java code in a JSP" rule.

```
 <% 
 String uri = request.getRequestURI();
 String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
 if( !"home.html".equals(pageName) )
 {
    out.print("<script src='" + designPath + "/javascripts/constants.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");
    out.print("<script src='" + designPath + "/javascripts/application.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");
    out.print("<script src='" + designPath + "/javascripts/cart.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");
 }
 %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Should try:

```
<c:if test="${pageName ne 'home.html'}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Contary to the comment, this does work (Tomcat 6.0.20) and [jstl.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%
pageContext.setAttribute("pagename", "test");
%>
pagename = <c:out value="${pagename}" />
<br>
<c:if test="${pagename == 'test'}">
equal
</c:if>
```

*equal* **will** be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Either != or ne are valid comparison operators in JSTL. Just be sure of importing the tag library with prefix **c**. And for sanity you should echo the **pageName** value. Just to be sure that it is different from 'home.html'.