# how to compare two strings using if condition inside jsp page?

Tags: java, string, jsp, equals

Jsp code:

```
<% 
String usermailid=(String)session.getAttribute("Username");
System.out.println("value of session==="+usermailid.equals("null"));
String empty=null;

if(usermailid.equals("null")) {   

%>                          



<% } 

else
{%>


<%}%>
```

output:

```
Apr 7, 2014 5:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.election_005fresults_jsp._jspService(election_005fresults_jsp.java:437)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In the above code i want to compare two strings.but when ever i comapare them i am getting null pointer exception when both the values are null and showing value as false??
so can anyone tell me what is the exact way of comparing two string???

Comment: `if (usermailid == null)`

Comment: Look here, there is a possible answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900843/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-jsp

Comment: First, the Most Important thing is Do not Put Java code inside the JSPs, it is very bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple check

```
if (usermailid != null)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(usermailid!=null)
```

try this it will work.

```
 String x = null; 
 String x = "null";
```

both are different

Answer (score 1):

> how to compare two strings using if condition inside jsp page?

#### Answer

**Do not write scriptlets `<% %>` in JSP**, because scriptlets shouldn't be used in JSPs for more than a decade. Learn the JSP [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and use servlet for the Java code. [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

So, I am posting solution using EL syantax.

```
${!empty Username}
```

Here `Username` is directly referred from session scope. `empty` is operator which checks for `null` as well as empty.

You can use `<c:if>` or `<c:when>` for conditional check.

```
<c:if test="${!empty Username}">
      //Username is not null here
</c:if>
```

### Useful links

- [Expression Language oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)
- [Tag if](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html)
- [Tag choose](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/choose.html)
- [Using JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)
- [Tag core](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting usermailid null and you are trying to compare with String "null".
see null is nothing(null) but "null" is a String with null as text.

Answer (score 0):

first remove this line:

```
System.out.println("value of session==="+usermailid.equals("null"));
```

u may simply write this:

```
if(null == usermailid) {
  // email id is null
} else {
  // proceed ur logic 
}
```

Comment: it is not checking condition and executing only if logic whether the user is inside the session or not inside session..