# How to change links in jsp files

Tags: jsp, jspinclude

My question is really simple and I know there is an obvious answer to this.  I am using jsp files and what I want to happen is when I click on page one only a link to page two will show up and vice versa when I click on page 2.  But when I am on either page a link to both pages still shows up.  Any idea on how to change this? Thank-you.

Menu

```
    <ul id="Menu">

            <li<c:if test="${param.active == 'Pageone'}"> class="active"</c:if>>
                <a href="Pageone.jsp">Pageone</a>
            </li>



            <li<c:if test="${param.active == 'Pagetwo'}"> class="active"</c:if>>
                <a href="Pagetwo.jsp">Pagetwo</a>
            </li>


    </ul>
```

Pageone

```
    <jsp:include page="menu.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="active" value="Pageone" />
    </jsp:include>
```

Pagetwo

```
            <jsp:include page="menu.jsp">
                <jsp:param name="active" value="Pagetwo" />
            </jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you doing in `active` CSS style?

Simply do not add the link if condition is not satisfied.

Show link for `Pageone.jsp` if you are on `Pagetwo.jsp` and vice-verse. Please confirm.

```
<ul id="Menu">

   <c:if test="${param.active eq 'Pagetwo'}">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="Pageone.jsp">Pageone</a>
        </li>
   </c:if>


   <c:if test="${param.active eq 'Pageone'}">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="Pagetwo.jsp">Pagetwo</a>
        </li>
   </c:if>

</ul>
```

For more samples have a look at [Is there an easy way to compare two strings in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900843/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-jsp)

Comment: If the issue is solved then don't forget to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply append the parameter to get single link at a time **tested and works for me**:

```
<c:set var="text" value="Pageone"/>
<c:if test="${param.active eq text}">
  <c:set var="text" value="Pagetwo"/>
</c:if>

<ul id="Menu">
   <li class="active">
       <a href="${text}.jsp">${text}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```