# JSP comparison operator behaviour

Tags: java, spring, jsp, el

I want to compare two different types in `<c:if>` tag of JSP. Basically left one is `Number` always but right one is a String and If that string could be parse to a Number I receive no error but If the String cant be parsed to a `Number` I receive `javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert No of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long`.

**Practically:**

> ${1 =="" } //works fine
>  ${1 =="4" } //works fine
>  ${1 =="Yes" }
>   //triggers the Exception.

But even the 3rd comparison worked fine in previous versions of JSPs but now it causes exceptions.

Has the behaviour of `==` changed over period of time?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: maybe internally uses a number converter if you uses eq sure that doesn't throw an excp.

Comment: no. Even eq throws the same exception in new JSP versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Behavior of `==` is not changed but behavior of `{expr}` is changed...

**About versions :**

In backward compatibility section of [JSP Specification,](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/)

> If the version speciﬁed is less than 2.1, then the {expr} syntax is
>   simply processed as a String literal.

So, till EL 2.0 all will be treated as a string literal and compared with `.equals` as `==` will be converted to `equals` internally ([Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1900896/1686291)), but in 2.1 It will not be converted to string and will throw exception saying that `javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert No of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long`

**About Comparision :**

In [JSP specification JSP.2.3.5.7](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/jsp-2_0-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1405083404_67ca5167219132660bc72763f4d44aef) of EL version 2.1, following is specified...

> 1. If A is null or B is null return false for == or eq, true for != or ne
> 2. If A or B is Byte, Short, Character, Integer, or Long coerce both A
>      and B to Long, apply operator

so, In first case,

```
${1 =="" } // ans is false as second one is null as per 1st rule.
```

and In second case,

```
${1 =="4" } // ans is false as both are different after coercing to Long as per 2nd rule.
```

Both will be coerced to long in above case with internal type conversion.

But not in the third case, 
`${1 =="Yes" }` where second one is string can not be converted (coerced) to Long and `java.el.ELException` will be thrown with message "Cannot convert No of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long".

Comment: can I do something to make my ELs in JSPs backward compatible?

Comment: I don't think there is any provision like that, unless you degrade .

Answer (score 1):

> As of JSP 2.1, the JSP uses the unified expression language (unified EL), which represents a union of the expression language offered by JSP 2.0 and the expression language created for JavaServer Faces technology.

It is very likely that the behaviour can be a bit different.

See section 1.18 of the JavaServer Pages 2.1 Expression Language Specification (available from [here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/)) for the complete type conversion rules.