# JSP : Getting "javax.el.ELException". Working in GlassFish, but not in Apache Tomcat

Tags: jsp, char, el

First look at the following code:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${type != 'h'}">
      <input type="password" disabled="true" id="plainText" name="plainText"  value="<%=key%>"/>
```

The above code is a part of JSP that I have created. Variable type is initialized using:

`pageContext.setAttribute("type", type);`

This JSP is working perfectly fine when deployed and used GlassFish Server but showing `javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert h of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long` exception when deployed on Apache Tomcat Server.

I had deployed on GlassFish server using Netbeans automatically, while deployed on Tomcat server manually using WAR file.

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: so of what type is `type` in your source code?

Comment: character type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, As `type` is a character. The following code:
`<c:when test="${type != 'h'}">`
should be written as 
`<c:when test="${type != 'h'.charAt(0)}">`

Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your glassfish uses an different EL version than Tomcat...

For more details:
[JSP comparison operator behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697840/jsp-comparison-operator-behaviour)

Also make sure that 'type' in pageContext.setAttribute("type", type) is a string and not an INT or LONG value.

Comment: EL version in Tomcat is v3.0. I am not able to get EL version in GlassFish.
Secondly, `type` is of character type.

Comment: Found the solution..Comparing characters is to be done wih `.charAt(0)`.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome :-)