# Using JSP EL "eq" or "==" with different object types throws error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, wildfly, el

I am in the process of upgrading a Spring application from Java 8 / WildFly 12 to Java 11 / WildFly 22.

It seems that something has changed in the way the Expression Language (EL) handles the "eq" or "==" operator (or something underlying EL).

When comparing a String to Integer, i.e. `1 eq "mystring"`, The old Java 8 / WildFly 12 stack worked without throwing an exception and would evaluate to `false` in this scenario.

Now when the page loads under Java 11  / WildFly 22, an exception is thrown.

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "mystring"
java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692)
java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1144)
org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:276)
...
```

*Side note: I realize this scenario is total code-smell. This 12-year long project was inherited by me and had well over 30 developers working on it from an off shore company. I'm now the only one maintaining it and I'm sure the JSP is littered with situations like this that I wouldn't be able to detect until I test that specific page / piece of UI functionality.*

What would cause this change in behavior? I have to imagine I'm not the only individual to experience upgrade issues like this, yet Google has not really provided any insight.

Comment: what _exact_ Exception do you get? You already have two votes to close this, though your question makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Eugene, I have updated the question with the exception details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698409/3635454