# How could I compare two string in Jsp?

Tags: string, jsp, substring

```
if(student_code.substring(0,3 )=="MLV")
  count1++;
```

But `count1` always return 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(student_code.substring(0,3 )=="MLV")
  count1++;
```

This doesn't look like a JSP code. It looks more of a scriptlet in JSP, which is nothing but java code. If that's the case, you still need to use `equals` for string comparison, like

```
if(student_code.substring(0,3 ).equals("MLV"))
      count1++;
```

If you want to substring and compare strings in JSP, use JSTL functions as shown below

```
<c:set var="mystring" value="<%=student_code%>"/>

<c:if test="${fn:substring(mystring, 0, 3) == 'MLV'}">
     <%count1++;%>
<c:if>
```

Also for above JSTL code to work you would need to import below taglibs in JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '==' symbols to compare two strings in JSP, I would put spaces inbetween and change the double quotes to singles, e.g:

```
if(student_code.substring(0,3 ) == 'MLV')
```

Hopefully this helps.

Reference post: [How to compare two object variables in EL expression language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900843/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-jsp)

Comment: Please read this post [How do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and understand why your statement `You can use the '==' symbols to compare two strings` should come with a disclaimer.

Comment: in jsp is valid, is translated to Object.equals()

Answer (score 0):

Oho friends .... I just change my code to

```
str1=student_code.substring(0,3 ).trim();
if(str1.equals("YML"))
  count1++;
```

..and its working