# Using EJS and HTML to add additional classes to an element where classes are already added?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I am currently trying to develop a partial templating file for a navbar using ejs, however I am struggling to add additional classes to an element which already has classes added to it.

I have tried 2 methods of adding the additional class, this is the first one:

```
<li class='navbar-item'<% if (pageTitle === 'Home') { %> class="active" <% } %>> <a href="/home">Home</a></li>
```

However this did not work so I decided to try embedding the EJS inside the class attribute, as follows

```
<li class="nav-item <% if (pageTitle === 'Home') { %> active <% } %>">
```

This also did not work, I have ensured that pageTitle is being served correctly as it is used elsewhere within the webpage and works fine.

I am not sure as to what the next stage is, I have considered using an additional JS file but that seems counter productive as I already have the ability to embed the JS inside the HTML.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make your life easier with a **Conditional operator** like this

```
<li class="<%= pageTitle == 'Home' ? 'navbar-item active' : 'navbar-item' %>"
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, it is more efficient and uses less code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be in the comparison. As a first check, in your second version try both '==' and also '!='. If '!=' gives you the 'current' class, you know that the logic in general is fine.
For more details, and an even better approach on how to compare Strings here, please have a look here:
[How could I compare two string in Jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902697/how-could-i-compare-two-string-in-jsp)

Comment: This was an interesting read, however the comparison here should make almost no difference. I had ensured that the value was correct that was being fed in. Thankyou for this either way.

Comment: I'm not talking about the value being correct, I mean that the comparison (operator) itself might be wrong. Hence I suggest to use the negated operator, to see if you get the right out come then. Also note '===' vs '==' and '==' vs .equal()' as in the cited resource. Just give it a try.

Comment: I did indeed look at the comparison operator, however in this instance it makes no difference as I am supplying an key value object pair via the express route, the value is indeed a string as it is static rather than dynamic.

Comment: Reading your own solution above, can you elaborate why it solved your problem? As I see it, you're now generating 'navbar-item active' instead of 'nav-item current'. Seems a bit like the issue was in the naming or in the css, rather than in the code logic...

Comment: Admittedly there was an error in the classes I added, however this issue made no difference as I was using the DevTools on chrome to check which classes would be added, there was still a persistent issue with the code not successfully adding the classes into the class attribute... I have now updated the initial post as to work more suitably.

Answer (score 0):

Using an if else statement, I have managed to develop an alternative solution to my own question. I came to this conclusion after discussing with a classmate who stated a relatively easy solution to this.

```
<li <% if (pageTitle == 'Home') { %> class='navbar-item active'<% } else { %> class = 'navbar-item' <% } %>>
```

This is not exactly as I wished for it to work but works effectively none the less.